# Please add accepted_date to answers/{id}

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred

The reputation timeline aggregates activity so that only one instance of each answer or question is returned for a given timeframe.  This makes it difficult to tease out reputation awarded for accepted answers because there is no way to know *when* the answer was accepted.

An optional return value of accepted_date on the answers/{id} call would make my life a little easier.

Comment: +1 but there might be a problem - checks can be reversed so maybe they are not tracking when just if. but who knows.  and welcome to non-lurker status.

Comment: @code poet- Thank you, it's nice to come out of the shadows ;)  I believe there must be tracking of when answers are accepted, because that information is available by clicking the envelope next to your name.  On that page, upvotes on an answer are listed separately from rep awarded for an accepted answer, and the time since the answer was accepted is listed as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced this is needed, nor does it immediately strike me as a bad idea.

So I'm taking the easy way out and putting it on the "consider for subsequent versions" list.

Answer (score 0):

Dave, is this resolved by the timeline_type?

```
  "timeline_type": {
    "description": "type of event",
    "values": "one of comment, askoranswered, badge, revision, or accepted",
    "optional": true
```

Lets get a check and a `status-complete` on this question if so.

Comment: @dave - ok, now i see where you are going with this, but let me argue with you for a minute: if you are watching in real time, then you know within a minute or so when it was accepted, so that case doesn't support the feature-request, whereas your initial premise of correlation of posts to timeline events might.

Comment: Obviously StackWatcher is the use case here, so: StackWatcher looks for activity and does not keep any local cache (at the moment, I may have to go there.)  If I query for activity sorted by date descending, I can get answer accepts along with the other activity.  No need for specific queries just for accepts, far fewer queries, and fewer total records returned overall.